# How can I show a ViewPager in fullscreen mode?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fullscreen, tap

By having an activity which contains a ViewPager inside of it, is it possible to set that ViewPager fullscreen (on/false) when it is touched by a single tap?

[image]

If not, I am going to start a new activity in fullscreen containing another instance of the same ViewPager and manually sincronize both ViewPagers `CurrentItem` which will require more memory and more objects to be instantiated.

What would be the best approach to implement this feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David Neto's suggestion is good.

**But**: You don't need to set the Layout width and heigth of all other Views to to 0.

What you need to do:

- Set the **Visibility** of all other Views to `View.GONE`, which is much easier

If your ViewPager has "**match_parent**" properties for width and height, than thats it. If not, set them to "match_parent".

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could set an onClickListener on the ViewPager to do something like this:

```
if flag == 0 {
    set the other Views surrounding the ViewPager layout_width and layout_height to 0dp;
    set the ViewPager layout_width and layout_height to 0dp AND layout_weight to 1;
    flag = 1;
}
elseif(flag == 1) {
    set other Views layout_width and layout_height to their normal values;
    set the ViewPager layout_width and layout_height to their normal values also;
    flag = 0;
}
```

Maybe this helps, not sure if it's the most correct way to do it but I think it will work. Also, this is pseudo code, just to explain the idea, it's not proper Java code (obviously) :)